# Structure of linux daemon

Tags: c++, linux, parsing, logging, daemon

I´m try to write a small daemon in c++ than run in linux.

I like that the daemon parse a iptables log file every minute.

What is the best way to structure the code, maybe a while true with sleep, threads, or another things?

Thanks

Comment: Does it have to be a daemon?  This sounds like an application for a cron job.  Less overhead, you write the program that reads it and cron runs it every minute.

Comment: Bit of a diversion but you could do worse than to take a look at books by Stevens such as UNIX Network Programming etc.

Comment: @Component10 - a very good suggestion. ISTR that the Stevens book has a specific chapter on how to write daemons and the associated pitfalls

Answer (score 3):

Do you need a daemon ? i.e. do you need a process running all the time ?

From the description above, I would be tempted to invoke a script to parse the log every minute via `cron`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, is easier using cron.

how to development parser with flex, bison, regualares expressions .. some other library?